# Диаграмма потока данных (DFD)

Tags: база-данных, блок-схема, связи

Необходимо построить диаграмму потока данных (DFD).

В основе лежит система Help Desk. Т.е пользователь заполняет заявку на устранение проблемы,модератор распределяет эту заявку по исполнителям,а исполнитель уже выполняет её. Администратор добавляет активы,кабинеты,пользователей, а так же редактирует,и удаляет.

Подскажите,правильно ли составлена данная DFD?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]